# Need some assistance with a variable in a Tic-Tac-Toe Game (Beginner Coder)

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

I am having some issues with my Tic-Tac-Toe game I am creating in C.

I have a variable called int cats (a cats game is a tie game) that is used to help in calculating and displaying text for a tie game.

I have tried pretty much all week to figure out how to get the game to tie. Even if you guys could point me in the right direction, that would be Sweet!

-Frendin

(P.S. The empty if statement at the beginning is for a player vs. computer game. If I can figure out how to get the game to tie, I can code that part no problem! Thanks again guys!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void printTheBoard(char boardPieces[3][3]);
int playerOne(char boardPieces[3][3], int cats);
int playerTwo(char boardPieces[3][3], int cats);
void checkBoard(char boardPieces[3][3], int cats);

int main(void)
{
    char boardPieces[3][3] = {'\0'};
    int cats = 0;  //A tie game in Tic-Tac-Toe is called a Cats Game.
    int choice;

    printf("Would you like to play against the computer or another player?\n");
    printf("Press 1 to play against another player.\n");
    printf("Press 2 to play against the computer.\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            printTheBoard(boardPieces);
            playerOne(boardPieces, cats);
            checkBoard(boardPieces, cats);

            printTheBoard(boardPieces);
            playerTwo(boardPieces, cats);
            checkBoard(boardPieces, cats);
        }   
    }

    if(choice == 2)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}

void printTheBoard(char boardPieces[3][3])
{
    printf("\n %c | %c | %c\n", boardPieces[0][0], boardPieces[0][1], boardPieces[0][2]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", boardPieces[1][0], boardPieces[1][1], boardPieces[1][2]);
    printf("---|---|---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n\n", boardPieces[2][0], boardPieces[2][1], boardPieces[2][2]);
}

int playerOne(char boardPieces[3][3], int cats)
{
    int choice;

    printf("It is your turn. You are player O. Please enter in the space you would like to  take. The first space is 1, continuing left to right, top to bottom\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        boardPieces[0][0] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        boardPieces[0][1] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        boardPieces[0][2] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 4)
    {
        boardPieces[1][0] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 5)
    {
        boardPieces[1][1] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 6)
    {
        boardPieces[1][2] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 7)
    {
        boardPieces[2][0] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 8)
    {
        boardPieces[2][1] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 9)
    {
        boardPieces[2][2] = 'O';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
}

int playerTwo(char boardPieces[3][3], int cats)
{
    int choice;

    printf("It is your turn. You are player X. Please enter in the space you would like to  take. The first space is 1, continuing left to right, top to bottom\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        boardPieces[0][0] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        boardPieces[0][1] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        boardPieces[0][2] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 4)
    {
        boardPieces[1][0] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 5)
    {
        boardPieces[1][1] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 6)
    {
        boardPieces[1][2] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 7)
    {
        boardPieces[2][0] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 8)
    {
        boardPieces[2][1] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
    else if(choice == 9)
    {
        boardPieces[2][2] = 'X';
        ++cats;
        return cats;
    }
}

void checkBoard(char boardPieces[3][3], int cats)
{
    if(boardPieces[0][0] == 'O')
    {
        if(boardPieces[0][1] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[0][2] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][1] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][2] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][0] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][0] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(boardPieces[0][2] == 'O')
    {
        if(boardPieces[1][1] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][0] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][2] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][2] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(boardPieces[1][1] == 'O')
    {
        if(boardPieces[0][1] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][1] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][0] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[1][2] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(boardPieces[2][0] == 'O')
    {
        if(boardPieces[2][1] == 'O')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][2] == 'O')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }




    if(boardPieces[0][0] == 'X')
    {
        if(boardPieces[0][1] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[0][2] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player X has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][1] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][2] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player X has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][0] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][0] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player X has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(boardPieces[0][2] == 'X')
    {
        if(boardPieces[1][1] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][0] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player X has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][2] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][2] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player X has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(boardPieces[1][1] == 'X')
    {
        if(boardPieces[0][1] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][1] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player X has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
        else if(boardPieces[1][0] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[1][2] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player X has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(boardPieces[2][0] == 'X')
    {
        if(boardPieces[2][1] == 'X')
        {
            if(boardPieces[2][2] == 'X')
            {
                printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
            }
        }
    }



    else if(cats == 9)
    {
        printf("There was a tie game!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: you check both players no one is winning and no more available moves.
This should be the condition for draw.

Comment: How about checking if the board is full?

Comment: by the way you don't need to use two functions `playerOne` and `playerTwo` you can use `player (char flag = 'O',char boardPieces[3][3], int cats)` and you keep switching flag from 'O' to 'X' ...

Comment: You can programmatically determine the column and row that an integer `choice` corresponds to by writing `boardPieces[(choice-1) / 3][(choice-1) % 3] = 'X'`. Check `1 <= choice && choice <= 9` beforehand. This saves you from writing _9_ `if (choice == …)` statements. 

Moreover, the methods `playerOne` and `playerTwo` are almost identical. Maybe you can move their difference to an additional function argument…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the functions `playerOne()` and `playerTwo()` you increment the variable `cats` declared as function argument. You should store the value in the `cats` variable you declared in start of `main`, e.g.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    printTheBoard(boardPieces);
    cats = playerOne(boardPieces, cats);
    checkBoard(boardPieces, cats);

    printTheBoard(boardPieces);
    cats = playerTwo(boardPieces, cats);
    checkBoard(boardPieces, cats);
}
```

A more detailed explanation follows. Consider the following code:

```
void func(int var)
{
    var = 2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int var;
    var = 1;
    func(var);
}
```

**There are two different variables with the name** `var` **here.** One is declared in the beginning of `main`, and its scope or lifetime is within the `main` function.

The other one is declared as an argument to `func`, and its scope is local to the `func` function. **This means that the variable and its value cease to exist when the** `func` **function returns.**

Now, if we want to use the value of `func`'s local variable after the function returns, we can:

- Return the value modified by `func`:

  ```
  int func(int var)
  {
      var++;
      return var;
  }
  ...
  new_var = func(old_var);
  ```
- Have `func` modify a variable in-place via a pointer instead:

  ```
  void func(int *var)
  {
      (*var)++;
  }
  ...
  func(&var);
  ```

---

Also, the `else if` condition to print the tie game message in the end of `checkBoard()` will never be run in your current code:

```
...
else if(boardPieces[2][0] == 'X')
{
    if(boardPieces[2][1] == 'X')
    {
        if(boardPieces[2][2] == 'X')
        {
            printf("Player O has won the game!\n");
        }
    }
}

else if(cats == 9)
{
    printf("There was a tie game!\n");
}
```

Consider returning from the `checkBoard()` function after printing the result of the game. Maybe consider returning a value indicating if the game has ended, so you can end the program when this happens.

Comment: I think a sentence or two would be helpful, about why the increments of the function argument `cats` in the functions `playerOne` and `playerTwo` do not effect `cats` in `main`.

Comment: @Lumen I added a few words about that. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I never even thought about that! Thanks for all the help and clairfying!

Comment: Got it now! Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner programmer. I just wanted to share my tic tac toe game in C++. I just wanted to share it because I think it can be created in a more efficient way if you use a for loop for putting in the values in the table.

> This is the main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "tic_tac.hpp"
#include <bits/stdc++.h>


int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    printf("-------------------------Welcome to the Tic Tac Toe game-------------------------\n");
    printf("Now steps to play this game is simple:- \n-> Enter the position at which you want to mark your sign.\n\n");
    printf("Just in case for position reference of the table\n\n");
    printf("  1  |  2  |  3  \n");
    printf("------------------\n");
    printf("  4  |  5  |  6  \n");
    printf("------------------\n");
    printf("  7  |  8  |  9  \n");
    printf("\n Ready to play the game(1 for YES and 0 for no): ");
    int start;
    scanf("%d", &start);
    if (start == 1) {
        game_run();
    }
    else {    
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> This is the function file "tic_f.cpp"

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "tic_tac.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

//I am using 0 for player a and X for player b

int game_run() {
    //This the vector to which we pass input.
    std::vector<std::string> game_p = {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "};
    bool game_on = true;
    std::string user_t = "A";
    
    while (game_on) {
        int user_in;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
            std::cout << std::endl << " " + game_p[i] + "  |  " + game_p[i+1] + "  |  " + game_p[i+2] << std::endl;
            
            if (i < 6) {
                std::cout << "--------------\n";
            }    
        }
        //Check if any user has won
        //Thus variable check if the game has tie
        bool it = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (game_p[i] == " ") {
                it = true;
            }
        }
        bool win_check = win(game_p);

        if (win_check) {
            std::cout << "\n\nPlayer " + user_t +  " won the game. Congrats!\n";
            game_on = false;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (!it) {
            std::cout << "Ohh, that's a tie. Nice game fellas.\n";
            game_on = false;
            return 0;
        }
        ;

        //This checks on which user turn it is
        if (user_t == "A") {
            user_t = "B";
        }
        else if (user_t == "B") {
            user_t = "A";
        }
        printf("\nEnter the position you want to make the sign: ");
        scanf("%1d", &user_in);

        if (user_t == "A" && user_in <= 9) {
            game_p[user_in - 1] = "0";
        }
        else if (user_t == "B" && user_in <= 9) {
            game_p[user_in -1] = "X";
        }
        
    }



}

bool win(std::vector<std::string> game_l) {
    bool what_r = false;
    for (int i = 0; i< 9; i += 3) {
        if (game_l[i] == game_l[i+1] && game_l[i] == game_l[i+2] && game_l[i] != " ") {
            what_r = true;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (game_l[i] == game_l[i+3] && game_l[i] == game_l[i+6] && game_l[i] != " ") {
            what_r = true;
        }
    }    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i+= 2) {
        if (i == 0 && (game_l[i] == game_l[i+4] && game_l[i] == game_l[i+8])&& game_l[i] != " ") {
            what_r = true;
        }
        else if (i==2 && (game_l[i] == game_l[i+4] && game_l[i] == game_l[i+6]) && game_l[i] != " ") {
            what_r = true;
        }
    }
    return what_r;
}
```

> This the header file, "tic_tac.hpp"

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

bool win(std::vector<std::string> game_l);
int game_run();
```